# Is there a way to prevent decimal output of a double calculation?

Tags: java, math, type-conversion, calculation

Got this code here and I was wondering if it were possible to make the output that comes from either calculation systems be without a decimal/stop the value at the point before the decimal point. Or even convert a double to an int without any errors.

Please ignore the pointless do while loop at the start, I am aware.

Thank You for any help.

```
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    calculation(getSystemChoice());
  }
    public static int getSystemChoice()
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  //create scanner
      int systemChoice;

      do{
    System.out.println("If you are using the Metric system, please enter a 1.");
    System.out.println("If you are using the Imperial system, please enter a 2.");
    System.out.println("To quit the program, please enter a 3.");
    systemChoice = input.nextInt();
    //Switch start
    switch(systemChoice){
      case 1:
        systemChoice=1;
        return systemChoice;
      case 2:
        systemChoice=2;
        return systemChoice;
      default:  //Currently no working input correction system, likely due to no case for 3. !!!! 
        System.exit(0);
    }
      //Switch End
      }
      while(systemChoice != 1 || systemChoice != 2 || systemChoice != 3);
      return systemChoice;
    }

    //This method takes an int as a parameter(1 or 2) and runs if statements based on the metric or imperial systems.
    public static void calculation(int systemChoice)
    {
      double inches, centimeters, meters, feet;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  //create scanner
      //if the user entered one, the result will be in meters and centimeters
      if(systemChoice == 1){
      System.out.print("Enter amount of meters: ");
     meters = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter amount of centimeters: ");
      centimeters = input.nextDouble();
      feet = meters * 3.28084;
     inches = centimeters / 2.54;
     System.out.printf("Feet: %.2f\t " , feet);  
     System.out.printf("Inches: %.2f\t " , inches);
    rerun(systemChoice);
    }
      // if the user entered 2 then the result will be in feet and inches
    else if(systemChoice == 2){
      System.out.print("Enter amount of feet: ");
      feet = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter amount of inches: ");
      inches = input.nextDouble();
      meters = feet / 3.28084;
      centimeters = inches * 2.54;
      System.out.printf("Meters: %.2f\t " , meters);  
      System.out.printf("Centimeters: %.2f\t\n " , centimeters);
      rerun(systemChoice);
    }
    }
    public static void rerun(int systemChoice)
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("\nIf you would like to make another measurement, enter 4.");
      System.out.println("Otherwise, you may quit by entering any other number.");
          systemChoice = in.nextInt();
      if(systemChoice == 4)
      {
        getSystemChoice();
        calculation(systemChoice);
      }
      else
      {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of potential solutions depending on your exact requirements. Other posters have already mentioned a couple. It's worth bearing in mind the pros and cons of each:

- Simply casting to an int or long is the simplest method, but will always round down. It's probably fine for your training example. But in real-world applications, this can cause subtle bugs with values that a double can represent but an int or long can't (e.g. a double can represent the result of 1.0/0 as "infinity", but casting to an int or long will turn this into a large positive integer value-- that can lead to subtle bugs in real-world applications);
- You can use Math.round() to use the convention of rounding to up or down to the 'nearest' integer; but this doesn't solve the issue of values that can't be represented;
- For other rounding modes, you can use the BigDecimal class: see the BigDecimal.round() method-- many applications won't require this, but some specialist cases might;
- To truncate to zero decimal places for output while also dealing with 'special' values, you can use String.format() and specify zero decimal places.

The code for the latter option would look as follows:

```
double val = ...
System.out.printf("Truncated value is: %.0f", val);
```

You've probably already seen the 'simple casting' option, but it would look like this:

```
double val = ...
long truncatedVal = (long) val;
System.out.println("Truncated value = " + truncatedVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use casting just before you print it and print it as an integer.

```
System.out.printf("Inches: %d " , (int)inches)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend simply casting to int. Here is an example:

```
double myValue = 8.65;
System.out.println((int) myValue); // will output 8 as java will always round to the next lower integer
System.out.println(Math.round(myValue)); // will output 9 which obviously is correct (mathematically speaking)
```

Comment: N.B. There are a whole host of possible rounding modes, though. What is "correct" depends on what your requirements are...